# How to get data from web service in android?

Tags: android, json, web-services, soap

I'm new in android development and I'm developing an application that can get data from web service. For example I created a login on my android application and the data that will going to input their is from the web service. How can I do it and what is the easiest way to do it using JSON or SOAP? Please provide some example so I'm going to have an idea how to do this thanks.

Comment: Hello,http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: **Check This Stack Question It May Help You**

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714578/android-connectivity-with-remote-databasems-sql/17714679#17714679

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JSON check this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).
For SOAP check [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/).

Comment: what is much applicable for web service? The JSON or the SOAP?

Comment: Example are obsolete, (use httpClient < SDK 21) besides that, you could provide a simple sample of code, since this is a "simpe" question. not a reference to a full scaled solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good example for this, im using something similar:
[enter link description here](http://android.programmerguru.com/android-webservice-example/)

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";

public void getFahrenheit(String celsius) {
//Create request
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
//Property which holds input parameters
PropertyInfo celsiusPI = new PropertyInfo();
//Set Name
celsiusPI.setName("Celsius");
//Set Value
celsiusPI.setValue(celsius);
//Set dataType
celsiusPI.setType(double.class);
//Add the property to request object
request.addProperty(celsiusPI);
//Create envelope
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
//Set output SOAP object
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
//Create HTTP call object
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    //Invole web service
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    //Get the response
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    //Assign it to fahren static variable
    fahren = response.toString();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Json is the most simple and clean communication protocol. I would suggest using a library for getting the data https://github.com/kodart/Httpzoid

There are some usage samples.

Comment: the source code is not working do you have other source code that I can use?

Comment: what about if user need to get more data from server.?
then how to handle that.?